# How could I "provide" VUEX's variable to my vue components?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, vuex

I used to do this in my main app:

```
provide(){
   return {
      authenticated: window.authenticated,
   };
},
```

but I don't want to store that in window.* anymore.
Now I have this:

app.js

```js
const store = createStore({
    state() {
        return {
            count: 0,
            cartItems: [],
            isAuthenticated: false,
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setIsAuthenticated(state, status) {
            state.isAuthenticated = status;
        },
    },
    actions: {
        async checkIsAuthenticated({ commit }) {
            const response = await axios.get('auth/check');
            commit('setIsAuthenticated', response.data.isAuthenticated);
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getIsAuthenticated: state => state.isAuthenticated,
    }
});

const app = createApp({ // stuff happening here... });

app.component(// various components...);

app.use(store);
app.mount('#app');
```

But I couldn't figure it out how to pass it to `provide`, so my components can keep working like before.

The problem is, `provide`'s variables are set way before `mounted()` is executed, and this is where I call the `getIsAuthenticated` method.

I can't use `setup(){}`, because there's no `this.$store` while the setup runs...

I don't want to overcomplicate it, but I can't figure out a way how to provide `this.$store.getters.getIsAuthenticated` to my components...

Any ideas? Why can't I set the provided value as mentioned?
Is it even possible to do that, without rewriting all my components to use `useStore` or something similar?